# How to check if the root HTML element contains a class from within a nested iframe?

Tags: javascript, css, class, iframe

I am adding a widget to another site and I only have access to the iframe which is well nested in the DOM. I would like to check if the :root HTML element contains the class "dark" and then only if it does contain that class to add a class name to my paragraphs.

Maybe it is not possible for safety reasons ?

here is the structure I am working with :

[image]

I have tried styling the paragraphs from another place - outside the iframe, the platform allows custom CSS from only one other place but it's very global and I wasn't able to access elements nested so deeply in the DOM and inside an iframe...

For the meantime I just used color: gray, it kinda works in both modes bou I am looking for a better solution -> I just need the color of the paragraphs to be white only if dark mode is enabled...

Answer (score 1):

You can access the parent window using `window.parent` and access the `html` element from there.

**Example:**

```
let isDarkMode = window.parent.document.documentElement.classList.contains('dark');
        
if(isDarkMode){
  // do whatever you want here, example:
  Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('p')).forEach(e=>{
     e.classList.add('yourClassName');
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you, actually what I need to do is -> first target the root element, then save it in a variable so that I can check if it contains the class that I am interested in, then write an if else statement. Only if it contains the class then to do further actions, so doing it in one statement is not what I need. and I tried `let currentStyle = window.parent.document.documentElement;` which unfortunately doesn't get me the element

Comment: @MonaCodeLisa I updated the code to provide you with full example. In the previous one I was just showing you how you can check if the html of the parent has the class.

Comment: Thank you for the changes, I will go give it a try now, not sure if it would work but definitely worth trying :)

Comment: Tomas (sorry for not being able to tag you successfully)  I appreciate your help, sadly I got his error in console -> `Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://embeds.hashnode.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
    at https://embeds.hashnode.com/?p=63ca78325ddf1a95769f6ada&w=about:64:32` This gives me the hint that maybe I am trying to do something that I am not supposed to... I think they don't want me doing that... even though is purely for styling reasons...

Comment: Ahh, the iframe is on another origin. In that case, you will need to use postMessage() API to do the cross domain communication. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage @MonaCodeLisa

Comment: Thank you so much I will have a look :) I have to say -> I am starting to wonder if just adding a white color to my text only in dark mode is worth all of that ;) but I do appreciate your help

Comment: @MonaCodeLisa in the src attribute of the iframe element, there is a different domain from your webs one